# Getting "undefined" return in readAsDataURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I'm trying to get a image file from a input field in my form, transform it to a base64 string, and then send it to my backend using AJAX, but it's returning undefined. Weird thing is that I managed to do it in a JSFiddle, but am not achieving this in the server.

P.S.: I'm not gonna write the AJAX call and server interactions, as they are not relevant for this issue. I'm sending more data, and it's getting sent just right.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="file" id="documento" accept="image/*"/><br>

    <button type="submit" id="continuar">Continuar</button>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#continuar").click(function (){
                var fileInputDoc = document.getElementById('documento');

                var readerDoc = new FileReader();
                readerDoc.readAsDataURL(fileInputDoc.files[0]);

                readerDoc.onload = function () {
                    var docb64 = readerDoc.result; //This is the point where everything goes wrong. Here I get the following error: "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null".
                    var doc_aux = docb64.indexOf('base64,');
                    doc_aux += 7;
                    var doc = docb64.slice(doc_aux);
                }
        }
</script>
```

It might also be important to say that I've tested separate parts of the code, such as:

`document.getElementById('documento');` (doesn't return null, meaning it found the actual element)

`readerDoc.readAsDataURL(fileInputDoc.files[0]);` (returns [object FileReader])

[Functional JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkg14tw5/)

My sources:

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/convert+input+image+to+base64+javascript
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: How big is the file? And why do you need a data: URL? Send your file as binary directly to your backend. If your backend needs base64 for whatever reasons, 1. it's bad, 2. it should do the conversion itself.

Comment: And are 100% sure this is the code you are executing (did you clear the cache)? Because there should be no way the onload event fires with `.result` being `null`. If the reading did fail onload wouldn't fire or result would be an empty string, but not null.

Comment: It's an image. My backend is a Python (Django) server, I'm planning to send it as base64 for a easier conversion to a file.  About the code, yes, I've ran verifications as well. It runs the whole code, just returns errors.